# Make a POST request and fetch posted data back to client

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need assistance in fetching data back to client as soon as it is posted to the database without reloading the page. The structure I have at present only shows the posts on page reload. Below are my codes.

```
const [pst, setPst] = useState([]);
```

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const v2 = PST_REGEX.test(pst);
    if (!v2) {
      // setErrMsg("Invalid Entry");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const response = await axios
        .post(DASHBOARD_URL, JSON.stringify({ pst }), {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          withCredentials: true,
        })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  };
```

**Post Controller**

```
const handleNewPost = async (req, res) => {
  const { pst } = req.body;
  if (!pst) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Field cannot be blank" });

  try {
    //create and store the new post
    const result = await Userpost.create({
      post: pst,
    });

    console.log(result);

    res.status(201).json({ success: `New post ${pst} created!` });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways from which you can achieve your solution.

> **Method 1:**

You can return newly created data from backend as success response. Lets assume you got response as follow:

```
{
  "message": "Data created Successfully",
  "status" : "201",
  "data": [{
    "id": "1234",
    "title": "Blog title",
    "description" : "Blog description"
  }]
}
```

Then you can simply add response to you previous state as:

```
setPst([...pst, ...message.data]) // message.data is response from your endpoint
```

> **Method 2:**

You can use socket io for real time experience: https://socket.io/